# Character to character regex when character the same

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture the text in a large markdown doc from on ## Header to the next for export into separate files.

```
##(.*?)(?=##)
```

Don't work because the initial ## is the same as the Positive Lookahead ##.

Is there a way to capture everything between each ##? Including the first ## but not the second ##.

```
Sample Text
## RegExr was created by gskinner.com, and is proudly hosted by Media Temple.

Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over matches or the expression for details. PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported.

## Side Bar
The side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference, and Help. You can also Save & Share with the Community, and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns.

## Tools
Explore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom results. Details lists capture groups. Explain describes your expression in plain English.
```

Comment: Make sure 'single line' is enabled (makes `.` match newlines). How to do this depends on the regex library you are using. Then you may find your regex actually works fine! https://regex101.com/r/lCg3CT/1

Comment: In addition to Ruud's comment: If you want to match the last `## Tools` as well, there is no other `##` ahead. You'd need to modify your regex to something like [`##(.*?)(?=##|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/lCg3CT/2) without single line you can also use something like [`##(.*(?:\n(?!##).*)+)`](https://regex101.com/r/lCg3CT/3) which would even result in much better performance.